# Laravel transactions - two type

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

In Laravel, it appear there are two approach when it come to transaction, which is the different and which is most common approach?

```
return $this->model->getConnection()->transaction(function () use ($self, $request) {

});
```

and other approach:

```
DB::transaction(function () {

});
```

Comment: It's absolutely the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually laravel transaction can do in two ways

**First Method:** Handle transaction and rollback on you requirements

```
try {

   DB::beginTransaction();
   //Db trnscations
} catch (\Exception $e) {
   DB::rollBack()
}
```

**Second Method:** It will handle transaction and rollback it self

```
DB::transaction(function () {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely the same, because you're calling `transaction()` method on `\Illuminate\Database\Connection` object. These are just different approaches how you access `Connection` object, either through `DB` facade or through a model class.